# Application extending class return null

Tags: android

In my Android Application the class MyApp which extends Application base class like this :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
   private static MyApp instance;

   public static MyApp getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     instance = this;    
   }
}
```

declare in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name="com.mypackage.mypackage.MyApp">...</application>
```

While accessing like this from an activity class :

```
MyApp.getInstance()
```

Return null and causes Nullpointer Exception some times mostly in android version 7.0.
I think this must probably due to application get killed. So how should I reinitiated the application class so that it getInstance() return non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

You should pass Current Activity Name.

```
 MyApp.getInstance(YourActivityName.this) // You should pass Context
```

For good approach use **`synchronized`**.

> A synchronized block in Java is synchronized on some object. All
>   synchronized blocks synchronized on the same object can only have one
>   thread executing inside them at a time.

```
public static synchronized MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance ;
    }
```

Comment: Isn't define `private static MyApp instance' and accessing using function getInstance() causes memory leak problems?

Comment: @KapilJindal Yeah! Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026563/3395198

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
public static MyApp instance;
static Context mContext;


public static MyApp getInstance() {
if (instance== null)
        instance= (MyApp) mContext;
  return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();
 mContext = this;  
}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this causes memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you

```
public static synchronized MyApp getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
```

In Activity Access like this suppose for Toast (for Context)

```
Toast.makeText(MyApp.getInstance(), "hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```